# Ionic2/3: Is it possible to open google map APP by passing custom lat- long?

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3, ionic2, ionic3

Currently i am working with ionic 3 project.

I have latitude and longitudes of particular location and want to get root of that location using google map Mobile Application, Just want to open that location by navigating to google map app.
do anyone here with any suggestions or idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean from your application, open up google map app to navigate to a custom place?

Comment: @Huiting Exactly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of 2017 the recommended by Google method is the Google Maps URLs:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action

You can create a cross-platform universal URL for Google directions following the documentation and use the URL in your intents. For example the URL might be something like

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=60.626200,16.776800&travelmode=driving

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Ionic Native Launch Navigator](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/launch-navigator/) now to load the native maps app to a destination. You can specify the app `launchnavigator.APP.GOOGLE_MAPS` or the user can specify.

Pass the lat long as first argument as shown [here](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator#simple-usage)

```
this.launchNavigator.navigate([50.279306, -5.163158], options)
  .then(
    success => console.log('Launched navigator'),
    error => console.log('Error launching navigator', error)
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

The recommended by Google way is using the [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action) API:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents

> Using Maps URLs, you can build a universal, cross-platform URL to launch Google Maps and perform searches, get directions and navigation, and display map views and panoramic images. These universal URLs allow for broader handling of the maps requests no matter which platform the user is on.